# export Lab nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem, I try using exports.something or global.something with the library Lab, but I have the following problem.

```
includes a lab script that is not exported via exports.lab%
```

I can only use it with the export in each file ?

My file of the test this case works.

my file of test

```
'use strict';

const Lab = require('lab');
const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const expect = require('code').expect;

const describe = lab.describe;
const it = lab.it;

const config = require('./config');

describe('CONFIG', () => {

    describe('isEnvironment', () => {

        it('Should have a property boolean', done => {

            expect(config.IsEnvironment('test')).to.be.an.boolean();
            done();
        });

        it('Should return a boolean (true) to pass a variable called test in function isEnvironment', done => {

            expect(config.IsEnvironment('test')).to.equal(true);
            done();
        });

        it('Should return a boolean (false) to pass a variable any variable diferrent of test in function isEnvironment', done => {

            expect(config.IsEnvironment('development')).to.equal(false);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

but I am using this case not work.

setup.js

```
'use strict';

    const lab = require('lab').script();
    exports.expect = require('code').expect;

    exports.describe = lab.describe;
    exports.before = lab.before;
    exports.after = lab.after;
    exports.beforeEach = lab.beforeEach;
    exports.afterEach = lab.afterEach;
    exports.it = lab.it;
```

importing setup.js

```
'use strict';    
const _ = require('../../test/setup');


const config = require('./config');

_.describe('CONFIG', () => {

    _.describe('isEnvironment', () => {

        _.it('Should have a property boolean', done => {

            _.expect(config.IsEnvironment('test')).to.be.an.boolean();
            done();
        });

        _.it('Should return a boolean (true) to pass a variable called test in function isEnvironment', done => {

            done();
        });

        _.it('Should return a boolean (false) to pass a variable any variable diferrent of test in function isEnvironment', done => {

            _.expect(config.IsEnvironment('development')).to.equal(false);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && lab src/**/*.spec.js -v; exit 0",
  }
```

my structure folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUeRK.png)